# Mybatis generator - Generate implementation for Mapper interface

Tags: mybatis

Mybatis generator generates the Mapper Interface. It does not even have a provision for generating implementation for mapper interface assuming that mybatis provides a default MapperProxy to handle the default implementation and in normal cases one would not require a custom impl.

Use-Case:
Need to override a particular Mapper methods implementation (say adding bulk insert support).

Question:
Is the solution to hand-craft the implementation for all methods in the Mapper or is there a smarter way to achieve this?